# Deep content structure. Entries at each level (Categories, Relationships or Playa?)

Tags: playa, categories, relationships

If you had this structure

- Main - Channel + Entry + Related/categories Entries
- - Main Sub - Entry + Related/categories Entries
- - - Sub - Entry + Related/categories Entries
- - - - Article Entry

Where each category from depth 1-3 contained entry data and lists of entries how would you approach it?

My first thought was to create a channel for each depth (fixed) , and associate entries at the article level with them (or associate articles with the parent)... but I wonder if native categories might be better, using segments to trigger channel information?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly once you get past 3 levels deep I start looking at alternate ways of building navigation. I prefer the Taxonomy add-on, but have heard good things about Nav-ee as well.

Comment: Thanks Michael. So far using categories, GW Codecategory and some templates at the top level (these wont change often if ever) - I have a working prototype...